# How to show $\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} \leq e ^ {\sqrt{n\sum _{i=1}^{n} (\log x_{i})^2}}$ holds when all $x$ are real numbers greater than $1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to show $\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_{i} \leq e ^ {\sqrt{n\sum _{i=1}^{n} (\log x_{i})^2}}$ holds when all $x$ are real numbers greater than $1$ ?

Currently, it would seem that the way to prove this inequality holds is to:

1. Simplify $n\sum_{i=1}^{n} (\log x_{i})^2$ to $n^2log(\epsilon)^2$ then get the square root which is $n log(\epsilon)$
2. $e^(nlog(\epsilon))$ equals $\epsilon^n$
3. $\prod_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}$ equals $\epsilon^n$

Is that correct? I'm struggling to remember how to prove that first step of the process.

Comment: That is not correct; you’re trying to prove an inequality using only equalities as steps. Start by taking logs on both sides, then look up the AM-QM inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$ \ln\left(\prod_{i=1}^n{x_i}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n{\ln x_i} $$
Using Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality you get
$$ \ln\left(\prod_{i=1}^n{x_i}\right)\leqslant\sqrt{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n{1}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^n{\ln(x_i)^2}\right)}=\sqrt{n\sum_{i=1}^n{\ln(x_i)^2}} $$
Taking the exponential on both sides gives you the result.